# Jdeveloper and Weblogic version compatibility

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

Can I use `Jdeveloper 12.2.1.x` to develop applications for `WebLogic 12.1.3` ?

As I can see from project's properties: **Libraries and Classes**. The jars that are being used (**JavaEE**,**JAX-WS**, other ) are feteched from the local installation of **WebLogic 12.2.1.x**.

Am I going to have problems when targeting a previus version of Weblogic(specifically 12.1.3)? If yes, then does this get solved by altering the projects' configuration or should I download and use `Jdeveloper 12.1.3.x` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your JDeveloper and WebLogic version the same.
For example JDev 12.2.1 uses JDK8 while 12.1.3 uses JDK7 so you might run into issues.

Comment: This can be solved by going at the Compiler section of the project and then at JDK Version Compatibility. There you can choose the Java version that you want to target.

Comment: But this won't solve the fact that 12.2.1 uses Java EE7 and 12.1.3 doesn't.

Comment: Can't Jdeveloper be backwards compatible? If I'm not mistaken I can use the latest version of Eclipse or Netbeans to develop for JEE6